# Akka not automatically join seed nodes

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, akka-cluster

I define an akka cluster with play app.

application.conf

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "192.168.1.100"
      port = 2552
    }
  }
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://application@192.168.1.100:2552",
      "akka.tcp://application@192.168.1.101:2552",
      "akka.tcp://application@192.168.1.102:2552"]
      auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
  }
}
```

Then I define a cluster listener

```
class ClusterListener extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive = {
    case state: CurrentClusterState =>
      log.info("Current members: {}", state.members.mkString(", "))
    case MemberUp(member) =>
      log.info("Member is Up: {}", member.address)
    case UnreachableMember(member) =>
      log.info("Member detected as unreachable: {}", member)
    case MemberRemoved(member, previousStatus) =>
      log.info("Member is Removed: {} after {}",
        member.address, previousStatus)
    case _: ClusterDomainEvent => // ignore
  }
}
```

And start my app like this

```
val clusterListener = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[ClusterListener], "cluster-listener")
  Cluster(Akka.system).subscribe(clusterListener, classOf[ClusterDomainEvent])
```

I firstly start the app on 192.168.1.100, it joins.

> Then I start the same app on `192.16.1.101` and `192.16.1.102`.

But the first seed node never receive a join event!

> What should I do, to let the other nodes join this cluster ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason. The cluster is defined in an object. And object are lazy initialized, So just call any method of that object at the Global.scala. Silly me!!!